# why cannot install/uninstall app using code on my real ipad mini4(ios10.2)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I searched from internet, got the below code, it works well on simulator, while it does not work on my ipad mini4(ios 10.2, already jailbroken).

-- does not work means it cannot install/uninstall other apps. I can see message as below if I debug from Xcode.
`LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.modifydb`

I also tried add signature using ldid, the same error.

My code is as below:

```
IPAResult installApp(NSString *ipaPath, NSString *ipaId) {
    IPAResult ret = -1;
    if (kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber < 1140.10) {
        void *lib = dlopen(KEY_SDKPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
        if (lib) {
            MobileInstallationInstall install = (MobileInstallationInstall)dlsym(lib, "MobileInstallationInstall");
            if (install)
                ret = install(ipaPath, [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:KEY_INSTALL_TYPE forKey:@"ApplicationType"], 0, ipaPath);
            dlclose(lib);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"path:%@,id:%@", ipaPath, ipaId);
        Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
        if (LSApplicationWorkspace_class) {
            LSApplicationWorkspace *workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];

            if (workspace && [workspace installApplication:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:ipaPath] withOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ipaId forKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]])
                ret = 0;

        }
    }
    return ret;
}

BOOL uninstallApplication(NSString *appIdentifier) {
    if (kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber < 1140.10) {
        void *lib = dlopen(KEY_SDKPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
        if (lib) {
            MobileInstallationUninstall uninstall = (MobileInstallationUninstall)dlsym(lib, "MobileInstallationUninstall");
            if (uninstall)
                return 0 == uninstall(appIdentifier, nil, nil);
            dlclose(lib);
        }
    } else {
        Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
        if (LSApplicationWorkspace_class) {
            LSApplicationWorkspace *workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];
            if (workspace && [workspace uninstallApplication:appIdentifier withOptions:nil])
                return YES;
        }

    }
    return NO;
}
```

The signature I used are:

```
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI</key>
<array>
    <string>CheckCapabilitiesMatch</string>
    <string>InstallForLaunchServices</string>
    <string>UninstallForLaunchServices</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.backboardd.launchapplications</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.springboard.openapplications</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS applications are sandboxed and cannot touch anything except themselves. This includes the operating system, and, in your case, other applications.

You're not going to be able to achieve what you are trying to achieve, it's restricted by the operating system.